# Creating new class references with constructor calls

Tags: c++

In my game I have a `Projectile` class that initially spawns on the right side of the screen either high or low (randomly chosen in the constructor). The `Projectile` automatically moves to the left side of the screen, and when it leaves the left side of the screen I want to redefine the existing variable with a new `Projectile` created by the constructor. However, I can't seem to get this working. I've tried defining it as `Projectile *projectile` but then my code throws the "expression must have a class type" error. How can I redefine it like

```
if (projectile.getX()<=0)
  projectile = new Projectile();
else 
  (projectile.move(x--, y)
```

I have the movement and rendering code working as expected, but right now the `Projectile` goes across the screen once and disappears.

Comment: Can you show the part of the code that declares projectile?

Comment: If `projectile` really is a pointer to a `Projectile` you have to call the member functions like this: `projectile->getX()`

Comment: In the header file I have `Projectile projectile;` and then just reference the methods in the cpp file (getX() for example)

Comment: @FlorianSowade, that's what I was trying to get at :).

Comment: @Chris if you want create the object on the heap it has to be `Projectile*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the line `projectile = new Projectile()` is that the return valued from the expression `new Projectile()` is a `Projectile*`, not a `Projectile` object. You're then trying to assign it to a Projectile object and that isn't going to work.

You should be able to get the code compiling by replacing that line with `projectile = Projectile()` if you don't want to convert the code to use pointers. Another option would be to add a member function that resets a Projectile object to its default state. The latter can be very beneficial if a Projectile object is expensive to construct and copy.

Comment: Just as a reminder: make sure you `delete` the previous Projectile.

Comment: Chris only needs to delete the previous Projectile if he converted the application to using Projectile*, if he simply continues to use the Projectile object, there is no need to delete the object manually.